# Can you buy a 3-day metro pass (for tourists) in Tokyo center?

Tags: trains, public-transport, japan, transportation, tokyo

I know it's possible to buy a 3-day metro pass at Tokyo airport but I missed that opportunity. Is it possible to still buy it in the center, preferably in the Asakusa area?

Comment: Unlike many cities, Tokyo's metro passes are not a great deal: at Y1500/3 days, vs base fares from Y160/trip, you need to average 4 subway rides per day every day for it to pay off. It's also not valid on JR or private train lines. Getting a Pasmo/Suica and paying as you go is both more flexible and cheaper for most visitors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Tokyo Metropolitan Subway website](http://www.tokyometro.jp/ticket/value/travel/), the only places that the 3-day pass ("Tokyo Subway 3-Day Ticket") is available in the Tokyo metropolitan area are Haneda and Narita airports and **Bic Camera** (Yurakucho, Shinjuku, Akasaka Mitsuke, Ikebukuro, Shibuya East, Shibuya Hachiko, Shinjuku East, Shinjuku West, and Sofmap Akihabara).

If you buy it at Bic Camera, you will have to show your passport in order to prove that you are eligible.

> ビックカメラ有楽町店、ビックロ
>   ビックカメラ新宿東口駅前店、ビックカメラ赤坂見附駅店、ビックカメラ池袋本店、ビックカメラ渋谷東口店、ビックカメラ渋谷ハチ公口店、ビックカメラ新宿東口店、ビックカメラ新宿西口店、ソフマップ秋葉原本店
>
> ※訪日外国人旅行者のみ購入可能 ※パスポート等にて旅行者であることを確認します。

If you are in Asakusa, the nearest would be the Sofmap Akihabara store or the Bic Camera Akasaka Mitsuke store.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative option is the Pasmo/Suica. I 'lived' in Tokyo for 6 days because it was just a short visit. What I found really useful was the Pasmo (blank card). A prepaid card which you can put money into it and use it to travel around on public transport around the metropolitan area of Tokyo (this is what I did) It's great because there are many 'stations' to load more credit on. The initial payment is 500 yen (deposit).

For your reference, I've added a link for more information. http://www.pasmo.co.jp/en/buy/